# Route53 DNS records stopped resolving

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

Last week, my TXT and other DNS records on Route53 stopped resolving:

https://dnschecker.org/#TXT/thuijls.net

The entries are set like:

[image]

What else could be missing here? As far as I'm aware, nothing has changed in the last week yet most of the entries are not being picked up. The domain was automatically extended earlier september if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

When I lookup your domain thuijls.net on [MXToolBox](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3Athuijls.net&run=toolpage#) I get the following messageL

**Dns record not found**

They explain this to mean:

> More Information About Dns Record Published
>   We did not find a SPF (TXT) record for the domain. Either you are using the deprecated type "SPF" record (in which case you will see a warning message for this alongside this message) or no record exists.
>
> For a SPF record to be valid, it must at least contain v=spf1

A TXT lookup for thuijls.net yeilds:

`Type   Domain Name     TTL     Record`
`TXT    thuijls.net     5 min   v=spf1 include:spf.messagingengine.com ?all`

The problem is the ?all - you probably copy-pasted this from somewhere and the (non-standard) hyphen became a question mark.

Edit your TX record to read `v=spf1 include:spf.messagingengine.com -all` and all will be good.

Then you can add a 2nd TXT entry for your  `"protonmail-verification-da....."` setting.